# Converting a list of strings into an indexed tuple list on Dataframe column

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with columns `tweet_text` and `lang` where I am trying to convert the `tweet_text` when the `lang` is `en` which are a list of strings i.e. `['The', 'Squad', 'for']` to an indexed tuple list `[(0, 'The'), (1, 'Squad'), (2, 'for')]`.

```
index  lang                                         tweet_text
3853     es    ALINEACION Este es nuestro once para el paidazo
4129     es                               fue el leon mas agil
4531     en  ['The', 'winner', 'of', 'GOAL', 'OF', 'THE', '...
6316     en                            ['The', 'Squad', 'for']
8367     en  ['The', 'group', 'stage', 'draw', 'will', 'tak...
8696     en  ['years', 'ago', 'Leo', 'won', 'his', 'second'...
10509    pt                              Os nossos guardaredes
10579    en  ['and', 'have', 'announced', 'their', 'AllNew'...
10606    en  ['TransEnterix', 'almost', 'doubled', 'climbin...
11289    pt                      Dia de Classico Dia de FC Poo
```

The code:

```
df['tweet_text'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(enumerate(x['tweet_text'])) if x['lang'] == 'en' else x['tweet_text'], axis = 1)
```

Current result which turns each character in a string into an indexed tuple:

```
index  lang                                         tweet_text
3853     es    ALINEACION Este es nuestro once para el paidazo
4129     es                               fue el leon mas agil
4531     en  [(0, [), (1, '), (2, T), (3, h), (4, e), (5, '...
6316     en  [(0, [), (1, '), (2, T), (3, h), (4, e), (5, '...
8367     en  [(0, [), (1, '), (2, T), (3, h), (4, e), (5, '...
8696     en  [(0, [), (1, '), (2, y), (3, e), (4, a), (5, r...
10509    pt                              Os nossos guardaredes
10579    en  [(0, [), (1, '), (2, a), (3, n), (4, d), (5, '...
10606    en  [(0, [), (1, '), (2, T), (3, r), (4, a), (5, n...
11289    pt                      Dia de Classico Dia de FC Poo
```

Dictionary of the dataframe:

```
'lang': {3853: 'es', 4129: 'es', 4531: 'en', 6316: 'en', 8367: 'en', 8696: 'en', 10509: 'pt', 10579: 'en', 10606: 'en', 11289: 'pt'}, 'tweet_text': {3853: 'ALINEACION Este es nuestro once para el paidazo', 4129: 'fue el leon mas agil', 4531: "['The', 'winner', 'of', 'GOAL', 'OF', 'THE', 'MONTH']", 6316: "['The', 'Squad', 'for']", 8367: "['The', 'group', 'stage', 'draw', 'will', 'take', 'place', 'on', 'Friday', 'afternoon', 'at', 'the', 'official', 'CAF', 'headquaers', 'in', 'Cairo', 'Egy']", 8696: "['years', 'ago', 'Leo', 'won', 'his', 'second', 'Ballon', 'dOr', 'Xavi', 'and', 'completed', 'the', 'podium', 'at', 'the', 'p']", 10509: 'Os nossos guardaredes', 10579: "['and', 'have', 'announced', 'their', 'AllNew', 'FUTURE', 'Z', 'boot', 'and', 'capsule', 'collection']", 10606: "['TransEnterix', 'almost', 'doubled', 'climbing', 'as', 'much', 'as', '97', 'on', 'Monday', 'with', 'volume', 'almost', '13', 'times', 'normal', 'after', 'being', 'ment']", 11289: 'Dia de Classico Dia de FC Poo'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem values for `en` in column `tweet_text` are not lists, but strings repr of lists. So is necessary converting them to list, here by `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

df['tweet_text'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(enumerate(ast.literal_eval(x['tweet_text']))) if x['lang'] == 'en' else x['tweet_text'], axis = 1)
print (df)

      lang                                         tweet_text
3853    es    ALINEACION Este es nuestro once para el paidazo
4129    es                               fue el leon mas agil
4531    en  [(0, The), (1, winner), (2, of), (3, GOAL), (4...
6316    en                   [(0, The), (1, Squad), (2, for)]
8367    en  [(0, The), (1, group), (2, stage), (3, draw), ...
8696    en  [(0, years), (1, ago), (2, Leo), (3, won), (4,...
10509   pt                              Os nossos guardaredes
10579   en  [(0, and), (1, have), (2, announced), (3, thei...
10606   en  [(0, TransEnterix), (1, almost), (2, doubled),...
11289   pt                      Dia de Classico Dia de FC Poo
```

Comment: Thanks just realized they were strings and not list.